# Keep old scope model in template while animating out

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I am trying to change the ng-include template and data in my app on button click.
When the next button is clicked I update the model and template. This is all working fine except the new title gets updated in the old template while animating out. Is there a way to get ng-include to work like ng-view where it keeps the old scope values while animating out and adds the new values to the view animating in.
Here is a plunker demonstrating the issue.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ddXbwXW4fz8viUMF5v4E?p=preview

```
$scope.templates =
```

When you switch to template2.html the template1.html title should still be showing in the template animating out. Instead they both show "Content of template2.html"

Thanks